# Elasticsearch Groovy Script Syntax for generation of nested fields

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch, groovy

The below simple ES Groovy script takes a python dictionary with order data (orderItem) and appends it to a list of orders within Elasticsearch. The list with all orderItems then resides under _source.Orders

```
"script": "if (ctx._source.containsKey(\"Orders\")) {ctx._source.Orders += orderItem;} else {ctx._source.Orders = [orderItem]}; "
"params":{"orderItem": orderItem}
```

In my use case, orders come from different shops and want them to go in to a list structure under _source.Orders.Shop5Hgk, _source.Orders.Shop86hG, _source.Orders.Shop5G60, etc. The shop names are dynamic.

No matter, what I try, ES throws exceptions complaining that Orders obviously is null.

> GroovyScriptExecutionException[NullPointerException[Cannot set
>   property 'Shop5Hgk' on null object]

So, what is the right groovy syntax to create the Orders field first, and then the field for the shop name and then append orderItems to that?

**Update: Full python function with (not working)**

```
def updateLastOrdersElasticsearch(self,data):

    es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(timeout=500)
    actions = []

    for shopName,orderList in data.items():
        for orderItem in orderList:
            sku = orderItem['SKU']
            action = {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "script": "if (ctx._source.containsKey(\"Orders\")) {if (ctx._source.containsKey(shopName)){ctx._source.Orders."+shopName+" += Orders;}} else {ctx._source.Orders = []; ctx._source.Orders."+shopName+" = [Orders]}; ctx._source.TimestampUpdated = TimestampUpdated",
                "_type": "items",
                '_op_type': 'update',
                "_id": sku,
                "params":{"shopName":shopName,"Orders": orderItem, "TimestampUpdated":datetime.now().isoformat()}
                }
            actions.append(action)
    return helpers.bulk(es, actions)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that initially your `_source.Orders` field is null, i.e. not even an empty array.

Moreover, `containsKey` might not be the right way to go, because your `_source` might contain a field named `Orders` whose type might not be an array, i.e. it might be a dynamic object standing for an existing order, or worse, just a plain string.

I suggest you try a different approach by first checking if `Orders` is null and initialize it to an empty array if not. Then you can append the `orderItem` to the resulting array:

```
{
  "script" : "ctx._source.Orders = ((ctx._source.Orders ?: []) += orderItem)",
  "params" : {
    "orderItem" : orderItem
  }      
}
```

An alternative to this would be to simply ensure that when you index your document the first time, you make sure that the `Orders` field is initialized with an empty array `[]` and then your script could simply append `orderItems` to that array.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments, I'm revising my answer in order to deal with the case where `Orders` is a dynamic object containing shop names as keys and each of those keys points to an array of orders for that shop. It's basically the same idea as earlier, just that we need to deal with one more level (i.e. the shop names).

First the script makes sure that the `Orders` object exists and then it makes sure that the shop array within the `Orders` object exists as well. All that remains to do is to append the `orderItem` to the shop array:

```
{
  "script" : "ctx._source.Orders = ctx._source.Orders ?: [shopName:'']; ctx._source.Orders[shopName] = ((ctx._source.Orders[shopName] ?: []) + orderItem); ctx._source.TimestampUpdated = TimestampUpdated",
  "params" : {
    "shopName": shopName,
    "orderItem" : orderItem,
    "TimestampUpdated":datetime.now().isoformat()
  }      
}
```

Comment: your solution refers to the (working) code snipped at the beginning of the question. I am in search for a solution, that allows to additionally add shop names to Orders and append the orderItems "shop names" lists.

Comment: Ok that's a bit different than your initial question statement. So `Orders` is not an array but a dynamic object whose keys are shop names and each shop name holds an array of orders, right?

Comment: Ok, can you at least ensure that `Orders` is initialized to an empty list at first, so that we don't need to take care of that within the script?

Comment: tried to do that in my updated python code example. See above

Comment: No, I mean when you first create your document in Elasticsearch, i.e. when there are no Orders at all. Can you make sure that `Orders: {}` when your **create** the document?

Comment: is there a way to create the Orders: {} on the fly within the script? Making sure that the field is there in the beginning would require a larger architectural change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99222/discussion-between-jabb-and-val).