# elasticsearch:use script to update nested field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to add a object into the `nested` field every update time.

For example,I have a doc:

```
{
    "test":[{"remark":"remark1"}]
}
```

Next time,i want to add a `remark` object into test field and save the old `remark` objects.And the result is :

```
{
    "test":[{"remark":"remark1"},{"remark":"remark2"}]
}
```

How to achieve it？

**Edit**
I use the script:

```
{
    "script": "ctx._source.test= ((ctx._source.test?: []) += remarkItem)",
    "params": {
        "remarkItem": {
            "remark": "addd"
        }
    }
}
```

But,i get the exception:

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
        {
            "type": "remote_transport_exception",
            "reason": "[es77][10.14.84.77:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]"
        }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "failed to execute script",
    "caused_by": {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "Failed to compile inline script [ctx._source.test= ((ctx._source.test?: []) += remarkItem)] using lang [groovy]",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "script_exception",
            "reason": "failed to compile groovy script",
            "caused_by": {
                "type": "multiple_compilation_errors_exception",
                "reason": "startup failed:\na8220b2cf14b8b7ebeead7f068416882d04fa25d: 1: \nclass org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ElvisOperatorExpression, with its value '(ctx._source.test) ? ctx._source.test: []', is a bad expression as the left hand side of an assignment operator at line: 1 column: 82. File: a8220b2cf14b8b7ebeead7f068416882d04fa25d @ line 1, column 82.\n   CILastCallResultRemark ?: []) += remarkI\n                                 ^\n\n1 error\n"
            }
        }
    }
},
"status": 400
}
```

**edit**

Now,i want to add a field to ensure update or insert the object.
For example:

```
{
    "test":[{"remark":"remark1","id":"1"}]
}
```

When i update the field,when the id exist,i will update the object.On the contrary,i will insert the object.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34512491/elasticsearch-groovy-script-syntax-for-generation-of-nested-fields/34512738#34512738

Comment: @Val {
    "script": "ctx._source.test= ((ctx._source.test?: []) += remarkItem)",
    "params": {
        "remarkItem": {
            "remark": "addd"
        }
    }
}..This script has error.Why?

Comment: Please update your question with what you've tried and the error your get.

Comment: @Val,I edited the content.

Comment: Replace `+=` with `+`

Comment: @Val,the script runs ok,but i want to change the requirement,and please help me to complete the script.Thank you.

Comment: @Val,script whether or not to meet insert or update object?

Comment: You simply need to add a second parameter to your script and then check  whether it already exists. It's just a bit of groovy logic to add.

Comment: @Val,Please give me an example,thanks!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest to try a script like this, which takes two parameters in argument. It will check if any of the nested objects already contains the given id:

- if yes, it will update the given `remark`
- if not, it will insert a new nested object in the `test` array.

The script goes like this:

```
def updated = false
ctx._source.test?.each { obj -> 
    if (obj.id == item.id) { 
        obj.remark = item.remark
        updated = true
    } 
}
if (!updated) {
    ctx._source.test = ((ctx._source.test ?: []) + item)
}
```

After being inlined and with proper semicolons, the script looks like this:

```
{
    "script": "def updated = false; ctx._source.test?.each { obj -> if (obj.id == item.id) { obj.remark = item.remark; updated = true } }; if (!updated) { ctx._source.test = ((ctx._source.test ?: []) + item)}",
    "params": {
        "item": {
            "remark": "addd",
            "id": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: {
    "script": "ctx._source.CILastCallResultRemark?.each { obj -> if (obj.id == item.id) {obj = null } }",
    "params": {
        "item": {
            "id": "2"
        }
    }
},Why this script can't delete the object ?

Comment: `obj = null` doesn't delete the object, but simply sets it to null. To remove objects, you need to do a different script.

Comment: You should perhaps create another question since the original issue was solved. We probably don't want to cram too much into this thread.

Comment: I create a new question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614880/elasticsearchscript-sometimes-works-ok-sometimes-throw-an-exception Thank you.

Comment: I am able to run this script and script works with success message but the data does not get updated to the elasticsearch data when I go and see elasticsearch record

Comment: for an unknown reason, this did not work for me.  However, this worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45234391/elasticsearch-updating-nested-objects . So, if anyone else runs into the same problem as me, try the link that i have posted.