# elasticsearch:script sometimes works ok sometimes throw an exception

Tags: elasticsearch

My `elasticsearch` script sometimes works ok,and sometimes throw an exception,such as:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "remote_transport_exception",
                "reason": "[es77][ip:9300]  [indices:data/write/update[s]]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "failed to execute script",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "script_exception",
            "reason": "failed to run inline script [newArray = [];ctx._source.CILastCallResultRemark?.each{ obj->if(obj.id!=item.id){newArray=newArray+obj} }; (ctx._source.CILastCallResultRemark=newArray+item)] using lang [groovy]",
            "caused_by": {
            "type": "no_class_def_found_error",
            "reason": "sun/reflect/MethodAccessorImpl",
            "caused_by": {
                "type": "class_not_found_exception",
                "reason": "sun.reflect.MethodAccessorImpl"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Here is the script:

```
{
    "script": {
        "inline": "newArray = [];ctx._source.CILastCallResultRemark?.each{ obj->if(obj.id!=item.id){newArray=newArray+obj}};(ctx._source.CILastCallResultRemark=newArray+item)",
        "params": {
            "item": {
                "id": "2",
                "remart": "x1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the es log:

```
Caused by: ScriptException[failed to run inline script [newArray = [];ctx._source.CILastCallResultRemark?.each{ obj->if(obj.id!=item.id){newArray=newArray+obj}};(ctx._source.CILastCallResultRemark=newArray+item)] using lang [groovy]]; nested: NoClassDefFoundError[sun/reflect/MethodAccessorImpl]; nested: ClassNotFoundException[sun.reflect.MethodAccessorImpl];
    at org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService$GroovyScript.run(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:318)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.executeScript(UpdateHelper.java:251)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/reflect/MethodAccessorImpl
```

i see the [bug](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17194).i will update the es version and try.

Comment: Which version of ES do you have? It seems this was [fixed in 2.2.1](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17194)

Comment: @Val,I update the ES version.and the script works ok.