# Unable to update the nested field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am working to dump and update the Elasticsearch data, I am able to properly dump the data but I am not able to update the records for example

when I do

`GET test/users/3985882`

I would get the following response

```
{
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "users",
  "_id": "3985882",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "gender": null,
    "user_mixpanel_data": {
      "event_name": "Detail",
      "time": "2017-07-01 01:37:43 IST",
      "email": "abc@gmail.com"
    },
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "user_invoices": [
      {
        "number": "54539",
        "orders": [
          {
            "order_id": "54539C1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now when I try to update the nested object `user_invoices` and need to update this, I am trying the script from the following question asked on SO i.e.
[elasticsearch:use script to update nested field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589963/elasticsearchuse-script-to-update-nested-field)

I modified the script according to my problem.

```
POST test/users/_update 
{
    "script": "def updated = false; ctx._source.user_invoices?.each { obj -> if (obj.number == item.number) { obj.number = item.new_number; updated = true;}; if (!updated) { ctx._source.user_invoices = ((ctx._source.user_invoices ?: []) + item)}",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
        "item": {
            "number": "54539",
            "new_number": "54540",
            "order_id": "54539C1",
            "new_order_id": "54539C2"
        }
    }
}
```

the above script gives me the following response

```
{
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "users",
  "_id": "_update",
  "_version": 28,
  "result": "updated",
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "created": false
}
```

Here the response shows the query was successful, but when I again see the same record I do not get the updated response.

Answer (score 0):

You ain't passing the id 
here

```
POST test/users/id/_update
```

Comment: this query format does not work with the script, we are looping all the values and matching in the query itself, therefore the above will throw an error.

Comment: "_id": "_update",
  "_version": 28,
you are updating it on id "_update",

Comment: This is the Updation query , therefore need to use POST method for this, GET will not do

Comment: you have to pass the id in the POST, 3985882, POST test/users/3985882/_update

Comment: I have tried the above suggestions you have given, But those are not working with my script, Not even by supplying the id