# ES6: Joining of subqueries to two different rows through the AND operator

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

I have following index:

```
+-----+-----+-------+
| oid | tag | value |
+-----+-----+-------+
|  1  | t1  |  aaa  |
|  1  | t2  |  bbb  |
|  2  | t1  |  aaa  |
|  2  | t2  |  ddd  |
|  2  | t3  |  eee  |
+-----+-----+-------+
```

where: **oid** - object ID, **tag** - property name, **value** - property value.

Mappings:

```
"mappings": {
    "document": {
        "_all": { "enabled": false },
        "properties": {
            "oid": { "type": "integer" },
            "tag": { "type": "text" }
            "value": { "type": "text" },
        }
    }
}
```

This simple structure allows store any number of object properties and it is a quite simple to search by one property or by more using OR logical operator.
E.g. get object oid's where:

```
(tag='t1' AND value='aaa') OR (tag='t2' AND value='ddd')
```

ES query:

```
{
  "_source": { "includes":["oid"] },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "term": { "tag": "t1" } },
              { "term": { "value": "aaa" } }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "term": { "tag": "t2" } },
              { "term": { "value": "ddd" } }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

But it is hard to search by two or more properties using AND logical operator. So the question is how to join two sub-queries to two different records through the AND operator. E.g. get object oid's where:

```
(tag='t1' AND value='aaa') AND (tag='t2' AND value='ddd')
```

In this case result must be: { "oid": "2" }

Searching data contains in two different records and applying MUST instead of SHOULD from the previous example returns nothing in this case.

I have two equivalents in SQL of what I need:

```
SELECT i1.[oid]
FROM [index] i1 INNER JOIN [index] i2 ON i1.oid = i2.oid
WHERE
    (i1.tag='t1' AND i1.value='aaa')
    AND
    (i2.tag='t2' AND i2.value='ddd')

---------

SELECT [oid] FROM [index] WHERE tag='t1' AND value='aaa'
INTERSECT   
SELECT [oid] FROM [index] WHERE tag='t2' AND value='ddd'
```

Do the two requests and merge them on the client is not the option.

*Elastic Search version is 6.1.1*

Comment: Is there a union operation. I know nothing about Elastic Search.

Comment: Union operation will not help. I need something like joining or intersect operation. See SQL examples above.

Comment: How does your mapping look like? In order to achieve what you want, you need to use the nested type, is it the case?

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve what you want, you need to use the nested type, i.e. your mapping should look like this:

```
PUT my-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "oid": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "data": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "tag": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The documents would be indexed like this:

```
PUT /my-index/doc/_bulk
{ "index": {"_id": 1}}
{ "oid": 1, "data": [ {"tag": "t1", "value": "aaa"}, {"tag": "t2", "value": "bbb"}] }
{ "index": {"_id": 2}}
{ "oid": 2, "data": [ {"tag": "t1", "value": "aaa"}, {"tag": "t2", "value": "ddd"}, {"tag": "t3", "value": "eee"}] }
```

Then you can make your query work like this:

```
POST my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "data",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "data.tag": "t1"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "data.value": "aaa"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "data",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "data.tag": "t2"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "data.value": "ddd"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Nested data can help me with current issue but it creates a new headache to add/update/delete particular properties of object. As I know there is no simple way to add/update/delete single nested row without update whole list of nested properties of object. My mappings was added above.

Comment: How many different tags do you have across all your documents?

Comment: They can be more than a few dozen. Usually not more than 10.

Comment: How about putting all tags as properties of a single document? i.e. document 1 would look like this `{"oid": 1, "t1": "aaa", "t2", "bbb"}` and document 2 like this `{"oid": 2, "t1": "aaa", "t2": "ddd", "t3": "eee"}`?

Comment: Last comment was not quite correct. I meant each document can contain a few dozen properties but it can be thousands of different tags across all of my documents. They don't have limit. So, determine single property for each tag also does not work.

Comment: Back to your first comment, that CRUD concern wasn't explicitly mentioned in your question. adding/updating/deleting data from nested arrays can be easily achieved [using update scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589963/elasticsearchuse-script-to-update-nested-field/36593499#36593499).

Comment: I will try your scripts later (now another tasks in priority) when my app will adapted to nested objects in ES. Thank you for all your assistance.

Comment: Fair enough, feel free to come back with questions anytime

Answer (score 0):

There might be one way, which is a little ugly: adding [terms aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) to your query body.

```
  {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "term": { "tag": "t1" } },
              { "term": { "value": "aaa" } }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "term": { "tag": "t2" } },
              { "term": { "value": "ddd" } }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": "1"
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
      "find_joined_oid": {
          "terms": {
              "field": "oid.keyword"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

If everything goes right, this will output something like

```
  {
  "took": 123,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 123,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "find_joined_oid": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "1",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "2",
          "doc_count": 2
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Here, in the "aggregations" part,

> "key": "1"

means your "oid":"1", and

> "doc_counts": 1

means there is 1 hit in query with "oid":"1".

As you know how many tags you are querying to match, say N, in the aggregations result body, only those "key"s with "doc_count" equal to N are the result you're pursuing. In this example, you are querying tag:t1 (with value aaa) and tag:t2 (with value ddd), thus N=2. You can iterate in the result bucket list to find out those "key"s who have "doc_count" equal to 2.

However, there should be a better way. If you would alter your mapping to a document like style, ie. store all fields of one oid in one doc, life will be much easier.

```
{
    "properties": {
        "oid": { "type": "integer" },
        "tag-1": { "type": "text" }
        "value-1": { "type": "text" },
        "tag-2": { "type": "text" }
        "value-2": { "type": "text" }
    }
}
```

When you want to add new tag-value pairs, just get the original doc with oid concerned, put new tag-pair into the doc, and put the whole new doc back into Elasticsearch *with the same* _id which you get from the original one. Most of the time [dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/dynamic-mapping.html) will work properly in your case, which means you don't need to assert mapping for new fields explicitly.

No-SQL databases like Elasticsearch and others are not designed to handle such SQL style query you are asking.