# Elastic Search: Parent child vs Nested Document

Tags: database, elasticsearch, foreign-keys

**P.S: We are using Elastic 6.x**

AS Elastic Search is upgraded few breaking changes are also popped out. We have some relational data which requires to be managed either nested or parent/child mode.

For Final decision I was wondering with following questions:

- How many nested documents/array size I can save in one field
- We have to manipulate the fields  often so whats the recommendation if we use nested field type
- What are the limitations of Parent/child if we use 4 types of relations

I believe, answers of the above questions can help me decide the field type, let me know if there is any other thing I should consider

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How many nested documents/array size i can save in one field

By default, you can have a maximum of [50 nested fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#_limiting_the_number_of_literal_nested_literal_fields) defined per index. In each of those nested fields arrays, you may store any number of elements.

> We have to manipulate the fields often so whats the recommendation if we use nested field type

That's where nested fields come short, as whenever a nested document changes, you either have to reindex the whole parent document or [figure out via scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589963/elasticsearchuse-script-to-update-nested-field/36593499#36593499) which nested document to update, but it can quickly get quite convoluted.

> What are the limitations of Parent/child if we use 4 types of relations

In ES 6.x onwards, you're limited to a [single `join` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html#_parent_join_restrictions) per index.

As it looks like, it doesn't seem like either nested fields nor parent/child would work well in your case... Maybe there's another possible design if you are willing to denormalize a little bit more your data, but hard to say without getting more detailed information about your preceise use case.

[Choosing Parent/Child vs Nested Document](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/choosing-parent-child-vs-nested-document/6742/5)

Comment: Thanks, i mean to be number array indexes in nested "nested documents".


as for parent child i believe i can add as much i want?

Comment: My data is like 


Users -> friends | blocked users |  Posts -> Likes | Views

Comment: I suggest you show 1-2 sample documents/records in your question, it'll make it easier to understand