# Partial Update on Nested Objects

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Good day:

I have this structure `Facility->Reviews`. **Reviews** is a list of nested objects on the **Facility** parent object. I need a way...possibly with **scripting** to say `insert new review into list of Reviews` OR `update review inside the review list only if review.id == param.review.id are equal`. I'm trying to get this to work as a partial update or upsert with NEST. Kindly let me know if this is possible with NEST.

Thanks.

Comment: The only way to do this is with a script update. Technically, the entire document is fetched modified and reindexed on the server, and you can control update conflicts with optimistic concurrency control

Comment: A sample script can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589963/elasticsearchuse-script-to-update-nested-field/36593499#36593499